# `new': invalid date ( ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ok i somehow get this error for an function with an date:

```
C:/geburtstag/app/config/initializers/update_year.rb:11:in `new': invalid date (
ArgumentError)
    from C:/geburtstag/app/config/initializers/update_year.rb:11:in `block i
    n <top (required)>'
```

The code looks like this:

```
 Patient.all.each do |f|
  if (f.birthday.get_birthday + 1) != f.year
   f.update_attribute :year, f.birthday.get_birthday + 1
  end

  if f.thisyear.blank?
   f.update_attribute :thisyear, Date.new(Date.today.year, f.birthday.month,  f.birthday.mday ) 
  end
  if f.thisyear.year != Date.today.year
f.update_attribute :thisyear, Date.new(Date.today.year, f.birthday.month,f.birthday.mday) 
   end
 end
```

Line 11:

```
f.update_attribute :thisyear, Date.new(Date.today.year, f.birthday.month,  f.birthday.mday )
```

I dont get why i get this error!! SO i made some test in the console, that all worked fine! I hope you can help me! Thanks

```
irb(main):005:0> c = Patient.find(24367)
←[1m←[36mPatient Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "patients".* FROM "patients" WHE
RE "patients"."id" = ? LIMIT 1←[0m  [["id", 24367]]
=> #<Patient id: 24367, vorname: "Hanz", nachname: "Schnitzel", birthday: "1961-06
-29", geschlecht: "1", drucken: nil, extraanrede: nil, extratext: nil, year: nil
, rund: nil, thisyear: nil, zuletzt: nil, strasse: "Lsu 15", ort: "W÷rth", pl
z: "93386", created_at: "2013-09-19 16:37:28", updated_at: "2013-09-19 16:37:28"
>
irb(main):006:0> b = Patient.birthday
irb(main):007:0> d = c.birthday
=> Thu, 29 Jun 1961
irb(main):009:0> month = d.month
=> 6
irb(main):010:0> day = d.mday
=> 29
irb(main):011:0> year = Date.today.year
=> 2013
irb(main):012:0> neu = Date.new(year,month,day)
=> Sat, 29 Jun 2013
```

Comment: are you sure all `birthday` fields are valid dates? For eg. someone has a `birthday` on `1981-13-32`. Other possibility is a leap year issue..someone's Birthday is Feb 29 of a year which is invalid for current year.

Comment: how can i check this and if this is the case skip this patient?

Comment: Hey **You are posting strongly private and confidential data about a Patient** (medical data), giving his first & last name. Please avoid that, it's illegal

Comment: create the date separately and use rescue..`this_year = Date.new(...) rescue nil`

Comment: @MrYoshiji dont worry, its an fake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to instantiate a `Date` object with invalid parameters, e.g.

```
Date.new(2013,99,1)
# => ArgumentError: invalid date
```

You problem is most likely not the code presented above, but the data you are inserting. Check your database for records that have invalid dates.

You can prevent such errors by presenting an error to the user upon submission when the date is invalid. In order to acheive that, you could add a validation rule to your model e.g.

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :birthday, if:->(d){ Date.valid_date?(d) }
end
```

Comment: How can i write something like this:                                              `Date.new(Date.today.year, f.birthday.month, f.birthday.mday ).valid_date?`

Comment: `valid_date?` is a class method, just do `Date.valid_date?(Date.today.year, f.birthday.month, f.birthday.mday )`